# Ошибка выборки из текстуры на границе текселя

Tags: opengl, webgl

У меня есть пиксельная карта. Я строю по ней геометрию, и там, где пиксель прозрачный - куба нет, иначе куб есть. Ну и фильтрация карты - `nearest`.

И заключается проблема в том, что `uv` боковой поверхности совпадает с `uv` смежной фронтальной поверхности (для того, чтоб "кубы" были как-будто раскрашены одним цветом со всех сторон).

И получается, что если ниже красного пикселя был белый, а не прозрачный (к примеру, пользователь удалил один белый куб под красным) (пример на картинках ниже), то на ребре куба образуется белая полоса:

[image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понятно, что проблема можно возникать из-за использования маленькой пиксельной карты, `mip-maps` или линейной фильтрации, но так как в моей браузерной игре я просто не могу потратить лишнее место на "гипертрофированную" png, то ищу обходные пути (конечно, я мог бы сделать большую текстуру из маленькой на клиенте, но это я сделаю, если не придумаю, как решить иначе).

(Сдвигать текстурные координаты чуть "внутрь" пикселя не выйдет, потому что геометрия рендерится с использованием quadtree, и я не могу гарантировать, что каждый квадрат из двух треугольников будет иметь сторону = 1 и, соответственно, быть окрашенным целиком в один цвет).

Возможно ли решить это без костылей?

Comment: Размер текстуры (и пикселя на ней) тут не при чем. Можете сделать хоть 1 пиксель на кубик. Дело исключительно в выборке цвета из текстуры.

Comment: @Kromster Нет, размер имеет значение. А я делаю именно 1 пиксель на кубик. И понятно, что дело в выборке из текстуры. Точно так же, как понятно, что это происходит на стадии растеризации и так далее. Если сделать текстуру больше, то выглядеть это будет чуть лучше. (Под больше я подразумеваю увеличить разрешение)

Comment: Как вы сэмплите цвет для сторон кубиков, почему на них нет такого же эффекта?

Comment: @Kromster у кубика 6 сторон, какую именно вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Толщину, те стороны что перпендекулярны основной плоскости вашего "QR кода"

Comment: @Kromster эффект наблюдается именно на ребре между боковой и фронтальной поверхностью, а не на какой-то из них

Comment: @Kromster вообще я просто проставляю uv для боковой стороны, которая имеет толщину 1, точно такими же, как и на смежной фронтальной. А так как цвет выбирается из текстуры с некоторыми погрешностями, то на ребре uv немного "не попадает" в нужный пиксель и берет чуть-чуть соседнего (которого и вовсе не видно)

Comment: Тогда у вас что-то страно-неправильно. Т.к. **вся** сторона сэмплит текстуру по тем же UV что и ребро. У них просто не может быть разного поведения. Или вы что-то недоговариваете.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47717/discussion-between-kromster-and-alexander).